# How to run linux binary with PHP?

Tags: php, unix, exec

I'm trying to run a linux application packaged in tar.gz from PHP's exec() function on a Unix server. What and how do I need to set up in order to do so?

Comment: `exec('tar -xzf /path/to/file.tar.gz && chmod 755 ./local/path/to/binary && ./local/path/to/binary && rm ./local/path/to/binary');`

Comment: You need to be sure that the binary is for the architecture you are running on. If it has been compiled on a local Linux machine and you want to run it on a shared server, it is unlikely to work, since the architectures won't match. But, no harm in trying!

Comment: I downloaded binary for x86 and it worked just fine on my server, lucky me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well first you will need to unpack the tar.gz to a directory. you can do this with exec(gunzip...) and/or exec(tar xvf ..). once you have untarred the package into a directory you can run the binary with exec() aswell. it really depends on the binary and on the permissions of the user you use for running php. for more info please have a look to php manual: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a person with little Linux experience I was expecting executable files to have  a specific extension, as it is in Windows/OSX and seeing that the files inside the gzip have no extension stumped me